# Dynamically assigning actors in Celluloid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrency, celluloid

I'm learning how to use `Celluloid`. I’ve read all the documentation and think I have the idea of how to use it but lack practise. I'm about to test it with a CSV file with almost 12,000 rows.

I’m unsure how many actors I should assign to a job. I'm guessing this number should be dynamic. According to [this railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/367-celluloid) the default number is set to the number of cores in your machine, but surely you should change this number based on your workload?

I have 12,000 records to get through, if I execute the code below I'm guessing it will initiate all the actors in my pool and queue them up to handle the jobs. But how should I gauge how many actors to dynamically assign to the work?

There are still many holes in my understanding, so feel free to challenge my whole implementation.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Celluloid
  def initialize(row)
    self.name = row[0]
    self.alt_id = row[1]
    self.definition = row[2]
    self.save
    self.terminate
  end    
end

CSV.open("./files/my_file.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  Model.supervise(csv)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your case you should create a different class for your actor.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.save_from_csv(row)
    new.tap do |m|
      m.name = row[0]
      m.alt_id = row[1]
      m.definition = row[2]
      m.save
    end
  end    
end

class CSVWorker
  include Celluloid

  def persist_from_csv(row)
    Model.persist_from_csv(row)
  end
end
```

Then you can create a pool and do the work for each row.

```
pool = CSVWorker.pool(size: 4)
CSV.foreach("./files/my_file.csv") do |row|
  pool.async.persist_from_csv(row)
end
```

Notice the `async`. That's what makes it run in pseudo parallel.

I admit I haven't tested this, but even if it Works™, you should benchmark it to see if there's actually any gain from paralysation. I doubt that it will be much faster in MRI because the only IO involved is DB queries.

Comment: Good idea giving the worker its own class. Why did you choose 4 actors for the pool? / How would you decide which number that should be? Thanks

Comment: It really depends on the task in hand. I've set it to 4 for no good reason. On MRI I guess 20 would be a better size. Just make sure your DB connection pool is higher then that. If it was a CPU heavy task, and you where using Jruby you should set that to the number of cores your CPU has.

Comment: Ah interesting, I am specifically considering Jruby. So the answer is just set it to the number of cores your machine has! Could you add that to the answer? Then I'll make it correct.